# Is it possible to use libcurl to manage raw TCP connections?

Tags: libcurl

Libcurl does a great job managing http connections. Can one use it to manage raw TCP connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible... But fairly complicated: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sendrecv.html

Answer (score 0):

According to its [official page](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), libcurl supports:

> DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, Telnet and TFTP. libcurl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, Kerberos), file transfer resume, HTTP proxy tunneling and more.

So, the short answer is "NO" it does not support raw TCP connections.

Comment: I have a strong business justification: I need to send ISO8583 messages. They are usually wrapped around a simple frame whose format may even vary.

Comment: Why don't you use the ISO8583 bytestream or jsonified one over http(s) ? That way you can use libcurl. Yet, you need the sender/receiver adapt it. Otherwise, you can simply use a tcp/ip library straightaway.

Comment: The other endpoint does not expect HTTP. It expects a two byte header with the size of the ISO 8583 message, that's all.

Comment: There are a few C and Python libraries for ISO8583. Wouldn't it be more straightforward to just use them? It is bare ISO8583 on TCP/IP so the other end-point will receive and be able to send back.

Comment: I'm already using libcurl for https connections. Just wanted to check whether I could use it to *also* manage TCP connections. There are certainly other alternatives.