# Unity doesn't work with neo4j bolt protocol

Tags: unity-game-engine, neo4j

Now that neo4j has dropped http:// support in favor of bolt://, my Unity projects can’t execute. The message is

```
Curl error 1: Protocol "bolt" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

The question is: how to get Unity to support bolt:// This means it would have to be a C# solution. If it won’t, how to revert to an earlier version of neo4j that still has http:// support.

There’s nothing in the neo4j or Unity developer forums about this.

Comment: What do you mean by http support dropped ? It is still supported in 4.4 : https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/4.4/introduction/

Comment: Interesting. There used to be a web page explaining that http:// had been deprecated. It appeared right around the time http:// stopped working. I guess all that complaining I did a couple of months ago got them to put it back. Anyway, it would still be useful to get bolt:// working with Unity. Note: my question is only about Unity, not .NET or anything else.

Comment: I don't think it's correct that they "dropped" or were even considering dropping support for HTTP API. There is an old _version_ of the API that is deprecated, but that's just an old version – maybe you're thinking of that?

Comment: Yes, could be. A couple of months ago I talked to a neo4j developer relations guy and he confirmed the change, so I guess they changed back.

Comment: Some HTTP APIs have been deprecated in the past, but the main ones are here to stay.

Answer (score 0):

Either you connect with the [Bolt protocol](https://neo4j.com/docs/bolt/current/bolt/) ([URI schemes](https://neo4j.com/docs/bolt/current/driver-api/#uri-schemes) are  `bolt://` or `neo4j://` or variants thereof), in which case you need [the official .NET driver for Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/dotnet-manual/current/get-started/), or you connect to the [HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/) in which case libcurl works fine.

But you cannot use libcurl to communicate to a Neo4j instance with the Bolt protocol.

Comment: Yes. Please note my question is ONLY about using bolt with Unity, not the general question of using bolt. Unity uses libcurl, so if that ain't gonna do it, is there something that will.

Comment: The bolt protocol is built upon TCP. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57950145/is-it-possible-to-use-libcurl-to-manage-raw-tcp-connections, libcurl does not officially support raw TCP.
Even if it did, you would have to manually encode/decode Bolt payloads.
If you cannot add the .NET driver as a dependency to your Unity project, you must use the HTTP API instead.

Comment: Thanks. I was gonna mark the question as answered, but can't find the button now.